# modify array multi dimensional php

Tags: php, phpexcel

this is my script

```
$cellValues3 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("$columnName$startRow:$highestColumn2$lastRow");
foreach ($cellValues3 as $value){
    $wh[]=$value;

}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wh);
echo "</pre>";die();
```

This is result array:

https://ibb.co/kgcaBe

but I want to result array

https://ibb.co/dLP8Ez

Please help me, I very confuse make array.
Thanks

Comment: A question (and answer) should be able to stand on its own without links. Links can die and make the question completely useless. Always include all parts of your question in the question. And never take pictures of text. Include text as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the foreach loop and use `array_shift()` to get each 1st and 2nd array item :

```
    foreach ($cellValues3 as $key=>$value){
                $wh[$key]['initial']=array_shift($value);
                $wh[$key]['nopol']=array_shift($value);
                $wh[$key]['ws']=$value;

            }

            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($wh);
            echo "</pre>";die();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to replace some keys in `$value` array. You can do it this way, for example:

```
foreach ($cellValues3 as $value){
    $first_item = array_shift($value);
    $second_item = array_shift($value);

    $wh[] = [
        'initial' => $first_item,
        'nopol' => $second_item,
        'ws' => $value,
    ];
}
```

Comment: If answer helps - feel free to __accept__ it and upvote.

Comment: how to remove symbol [ ] ? 
I want to just one symbol on array

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: result the array as on image https://ibb.co/nrsbjz
I want to remove symbol [ ] change with symbol { }

Comment: It's useless operation. You have access to these items in javascript (and any other languages) both with `{}` and `[]`.